# Creating Key/Value JSON object with random integers and Flask

Tags: python, json, random, flask

I recently was asked for homework to expand upon a Flask application so that a route is created which will roll two dice and return the outcome as a JSON object.

I thought I had completed the program correctly but was disappointed to find out that what my code is producing is not a JSON object?

Would anyone know how I would take the code below and return the dice roll as a key/value pair? At this point in time when I visit the `rolldice` route the output is Jsonified as the sum of the two dice rolls. I'm not sure how I can turn this into a key/value pair. Any help is appreciated, thanks again.

Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

import json
import random

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

# Create a route and function for rolling dice.
@app.route('/rolldice')
def dieobject():
    # Define rollcount
    rollcount = []
    # Define the number of times we will roll two dice.
    for i in range(0, 1):
        # Define rolling two dice.
        two_dieobject = random.randint(1, 6) + random.randint(1, 6)
        # Take output of our dice roll and pass it to rollcount.
        rollcount.append(two_dieobject)
    # Return the value of rollcount as JSON Data.
    # Data will be presented as one integer which is the sum of two dice rolls.
    return jsonify(rollcount)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

And for those who asked here is the output I am recieving:

```
[
  7
]
```

Where the integer presented is the sum of the two dice rolls.

Comment: Python `list`s get serialized to json arrays... not json objects. You want a `dict`. Maybe you want something like `{'roll1':2, 'roll2':5}`. Only you can say, really, what sort of output you want... You should probably be explicit about that.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the output that I am seeing. My mistake for not including it earlier.

Comment: As far as output goes, what about something like [this](https://pastebin.com/J8Z62ck5)? So the data shows the value and the number of dice rolled to get that value.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I'm guessing that I need as that is a Key/Value pair representation of what's happening. Since the only output my code gives is the sum It can't be counted as a Key/Value pair?

Comment: Ok I see, now I understand. Thanks again for your help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this. It does the rolls in a loop and adds them together using the `sum` function.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import random

app = Flask(__name__)


def roll(numrolls=1):
    return sum(random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(numrolls))


@app.route('/rolldice')
def dieobject():

    # make dictionary here
    return jsonify({'value': roll(numrolls=2), 'rolls': 2})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I expanded it a bit. It returns a the roll value and the number of dice used to get that value. You could expand it again to have the flask service take a parameter stating how many dice to roll if you wanted.

Output

```
{
  "rolls": 2, 
  "value": 7
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help with this, my main confusion was stemming from not understanding why my output was not considered and object.

Comment: yes seems an array is not considered an object in the json sense, although it is clearly valid json. It follows the javascript notion of what an object is i.e. a hashmap/dict type thing (with a few extras). if you look on the front page of http://www.json.org/ it shows some definitions on the right side.